# Please suggest the linux machine configuration to run 10000 user test with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Now I am using windows machines to run the performance test with 6000 users following are the windows machine details.

Windows
RAM: 32GB
CPU: 8 Core
(executed in distributed systems with three machines)

Now we are planning to run the test in Linux environment with 10000 users. I am very new to Linux system, 
please suggest me which configuration would work for this test in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably given you have the same hardware specifications for Linux machines you should be able to kick off at least as many users as on Windows as JMeter doesn't know anything about underlying OS as it is being run inside the [Java Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

In general no one can answer except you as the number of virtual users varies depending on many factors (OS and JVM configuration, nature of your test, number of requests, request size, number of [pre processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [post-processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions), etc.)

The approach should be like:

1. Make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure you have monitoring of baseline OS health metrics in place for JMeter engine (you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin for that](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/))
3. Start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load at the same time keeping an eye on CPU, RAM, Swap, disks and network usage. Once any of these metrics exceeds reasonable threshold (say 90% of maximum available capacity) stop the test and mention the number of active users at this stage (for example with [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/))
4. This is how many users you can simulate on particular this machine for particular this test. If you change the test or host - you will need to re-do the measurement.

See [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation.

Comment: So what are the numbers on your windows machine? That might give you an idea of what room you might have, or not.
Your current setup could be your 'baseline', as already mentioned, a similar linux machine should be able to perform similar. 

Did you look into distributed testing (see: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)? That way you can divide the load over multiple machines and scale your needs.

Answer (score 0):

How many resources do each of your virtual users consume from the finite resource pool of CPU, Disk, Memory and Network?

You want to avoid anything over 80% CPU or you will edge into instruction queuing fast, over 30% on the Network for Ethernet Collisions and Retransmits, Anything that ventures into heavy swapping for your virtual user processes on Memory and when your lock/read/write waits tend over disk seek time by 150% you are stalled, waiting on disk.  This leads to longer timing records due to delays inside of the timer.

I know, not the answer you want. Every business process built into a virtual user takes a different amount of resource to execute, hence there is not a reliable way to suggest that you can get X of any type on a host without understanding the resource pool of the hosts and the resource take of the virtual users.  Also, the less mature the tester the "Fatter" the resource hit on the pool due to poor practices on logging, memory use, configuration of the server related to cache, etc...

And good going for at least three load generators.   As a side note, you may want to consider one of your load generator pool for control purposes as this would help you to understand any load generator imposed delays on your timing records. Simply include one load generator of identical hardware to the rest in your load generator pool, but only execute a single virtual user of each script type.  If your virtual users for your control and non control generators degrade at the same rate then you can be assured that a common external source, the application under test, is the primary influence.  However if you seek to place as many users on a host as possible, then you will often find that the performance reported by the control and non control groups differ because of resource dependencies which are coloring your timing records on the oversubscribed hosts.   Food for thought on hardening your tests and providing backup when someone who doesn't like your results wants to blame the test instead of the accepting that the baby is, in fact, ugly.